# How to add a query to a webpack loader with multiple loaders?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, webpack, babeljs

I have this Babel loader that's working

```
{ test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'babel', query: babelSettings, exclude: /node_modules/ },
```

But now I want a CoffeeScript loader but I want to pipe it through Babel to get the the fancy HMR stuff

```
{ test: /\.coffee$/, loader: 'babel!coffee', query: babelSettings, exclude: /node_modules/ },
```

This doesn't work though, and results in the following error.

> Error: Cannot define 'query' and multiple loaders in loaders list

Any idea how to define the query just for the Babel part of the loader chain? The query is a complicated object and I don't think I can encode it.

```
var babelSettings = { stage: 0 };

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  babelSettings.plugins = ['react-transform'];
  babelSettings.extra = {
    'react-transform': {
      transforms: [{
        transform: 'react-transform-hmr',
        imports: ['react'],
        locals: ['module']
      }, {
        transform: 'react-transform-catch-errors',
        imports: ['react', 'redbox-react']
      }]
      // redbox-react is breaking the line numbers :-(
      // you might want to disable it
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 30):

**Update:** With non-legacy versions of Webpack [you can define an array of loaders in the Webpack configuration](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#configuration).

If you need to use an older versions of Webpack or add the options inline, the original answer is below.

---

The way to do this is to set the query parameters in the loader string itself, as the `query` object key will only work for one loader.

Assuming your settings object can be serialized to JSON, as your example indicates, you could easily pass your settings object as a JSON query. Then only the Babel loader will get the settings.

```
{ test: /\.coffee$/, loader: 'babel?'+JSON.stringify(babelSettings)+'!coffee', exclude: /node_modules/ }
```

The feature for doing this is somewhat documented here:

> **[Using Loaders: Query parameters](https://webpack.github.io/docs/using-loaders.html#query-parameters)**
>
> Most loaders accept parameters in the normal query format (`?key=value&key2=value2`) and as JSON object (`?{"key":"value","key2":"value2"}`).

Answer (score 14):

Sokra, the creator of Webpack, gives his own take on how to do this [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/482#issuecomment-56161239), but you'll probably be better served with the [webpack-combine-loaders](https://github.com/jsdf/webpack-combine-loaders) helper that's more similar in style to defining a single loader with the query object.

With `webpack-combine-loaders`, you can define multiple loaders as such:

```
combineLoaders([
  {
    loader: 'css-loader',
    query: {
      modules: true,
      sourceMap: true,
      localIdentName: '[name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
    },
  },
  {
    loader: 'sass-loader',
    query: {
      sourceMap: true,
      includePaths: [
        'app/assets/stylesheets',
        'app/assets/stylesheets/legacy',
      ],
    },
  },
]);
```

Answer (score 13):

In **webpack 2 & 3** this can be configured much more cleanly.

Loaders can be passed in an array of loader objects. Each loader object can specify an `options` object that acts like the webpack 1 `query` for that particular loader.

For example, using both `react-hot-loader` and `babel-loader`, with `babel-loader` configured with some options, in **webpack 2 & 3**

```
module: {
  rules: [{
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [{
      loader: 'react-hot-loader'
    }, {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        babelrc: false,
        presets: [
          'es2015-native-modules',
          'stage-0',
          'react'
        ]
      }
    }]
  }] 
}
```

For comparison, here is the same configuration in **webpack 1**, using the query string method.

```
module: {
  loaders: [{
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loaders: [
      'react-hot',
      'babel-loader?' +
        'babelrc=false,' +
        'presets[]=es2015,' +
        'presets[]=stage-0,' +
        'presets[]=react'
      ]
  }] 
}
```

*Notice the changed property names all down the chain.*

*Also, note that I changed the `es2015` preset to `es2015-native-modules` preset in the `babel-loader` configuration. This has nothing to do with the specification of `options`, it's just that including es6 modules allows you to use the tree-shaking feature introduced in v2. It could be left alone and it would still work, but the answer would feel incomplete without that obvious upgrade being pointed out :-)*

Answer (score 3):

The `test` property is just regex, so you can run a check for both jsx and coffee at the same time:

`test: /\.(jsx|coffee)$/`

Sass/SCSS is a little easier:

`test: /\.s[ac]ss$/`