# How to write webpack.config.js when set more param?

Tags: config, webpack, reactjs

I want to handle my jsx code, so I write webpakc.config.js like this:

```js
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015'],
    exclude: /node_modules/
}
```

But it didn't handle my jsx code and throw an error like this:
[The error threw in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pW8u.jpg)

By Google I find I need to add `presets['react']` to my config file. So I update config like this:

```js
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
    query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015']
    },
    exclude: /node_modules/
}
```

But it threw another error:
[A new error threw after update config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VR5kE.jpg)

I am a fresher in webpack, What should I do?

Comment: the first error: ERROR in ./src/App.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /Users/wen/Documents/SDE/Olege/olege-webApp/src/App.js: Unexpected token (4:9)
  2 | class App extends Component {
  3 |  render(){
> 4 |   return <h1></h1>
    |          ^
  5 |  }
  6 | }

Comment: The second error: /Users/wen/Documents/SDE/Olege/olege-webApp/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/LoadersList.js:54
  if(!element.loader || element.loader.indexOf("!") >= 0) throw new Error("Cannot define 'query' and multiple loaders in loaders list");
                                                          ^

Error: Cannot define 'query' and multiple loaders in loaders list

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the errors so they don't get lost in the comments?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a query to a webpack loader with multiple loaders?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117136/how-to-add-a-query-to-a-webpack-loader-with-multiple-loaders)

Answer (score 13):

The first error seems to be a syntax error in your JSX. Difficult to tell what it is from the comment. Try posting the JSX file contents.

About the second error: 
Query params for a specific loader needn't necessarily be specified as a JSON object. You can specify them as a query string adjoining the loader name as well. Eg. the same config can be expressed with this line:

```
loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015']
```

Of course, you'll need to remove the query JSON once you use the above.
More info here: https://webpack.github.io/docs/using-loaders.html#query-parameters

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you.