# Webpack - Error: Cannot define 'query' and multiple loaders in loaders list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-hot-loader

This error appeared after I added the `react-hot` loader in an array following this tutorial: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/setting-up-webpack-for-react-and-hot-module-replacement

I'm getting `Error: Cannot define 'query' and multiple loaders in loaders list`.

```
var WebpackDevServer = require("webpack-dev-server");
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
require("babel-polyfill");

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    'bootstrap-loader',
    'webpack/hot/dev-server',
    APP_DIR + '/import.js',
  ],
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      query: {
        plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
        presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react']
      }
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
    }, {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
    }, {
      test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
      loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
    }]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery"
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ]
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a query to a webpack loader with multiple loaders?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117136/how-to-add-a-query-to-a-webpack-loader-with-multiple-loaders)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

It seems that the query is an alternative way of customizing the behaviour of a *single* loader, that is cleaner than specifying those parameters inline (see below). If multiple loaders are present, Webpack does not know to which the `query` configuration applies.

The following should solve your problem:

```
module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel?presets[]=es2015,presets[]=stage-0,presets[]=react,plugins[]=transform-runtime']
    }
```

---

**EDIT:** While this solution works for Webpack 1, see the other answers for cleaner solutions that work in more recent versions.

Comment: Thank you for posting this solution

Comment: For complicated query, use [`webpack-combine-loaders`](https://github.com/jsdf/webpack-combine-loaders).

Answer (score 18):

My Solution:

```
loaders: [{
  test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
  loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel?' + JSON.stringify({
    cacheDirectory: true,
    plugins: [
      'transform-runtime',
      'transform-decorators-legacy'
    ],
    presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0'],
    env: {
      production: {
        presets: ['react-optimize']
      }
    }
  }), 'eslint'],
  include: src,
  exclude: /node_modules/
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of JSON.stringify :)

Answer (score 10):

In **webpack 2 & 3** this can be configured much more cleanly.

Loaders can be passed in an array of loader objects. Each loader object can specify an `options` object that acts like the webpack 1 `query` for that particular loader.

For example, using both `react-hot-loader` and `babel-loader`, with `babel-loader` configured with some options, in **webpack 2/3**

```
module: {
  rules: [{
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [{
      loader: 'react-hot-loader'
    }, {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        babelrc: false,
        presets: [
          'es2015-native-modules'
          'stage-0',
          'react'
        ]
      }
    }]
  }] 
}
```

For comparison, here is the same configuration in **webpack 1**, using the query string method.

```
module: {
  rules: [{
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loaders: [
      'react-hot',
      'babel-loader?' +
        'babelrc=false,' +
        'presets[]=es2015,' +
        'presets[]=stage-0,' +
        'presets[]=react'
      ]
  }] 
}
```

*Notice the changed property names all down the chain.*

*Also, note that I changed the `es2015` preset to `es2015-native-modules` preset in the `babel-loader` configuration. This has nothing to do with the specification of `options`, it's just that including es6 modules allows you to use webpack tree-shaking feature introduced in v2. It could be left alone and it would still work, but the answer would feel incomplete without that obvious upgrade being pointed out :-)*

---

*Disclaimer: This is the same as my answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117136/how-to-add-a-query-to-a-webpack-loader-with-multiple-loaders/41779562#41779562), but this question has similar votes/views/google ranking, so I'll post the answer here too.*

---

Answer (score 1):

For **webpack 2**. I manage to configure like this:

```
    var webpack = require("webpack");
    var path = require("path");

    module.exports = {
        entry: "./src/index.js",
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/assets"),
            filename: "bundle.js",
            publicPath: "/assets/"
        },
        devServer: {
            inline: true,
            contentBase: './dist',
            port: 3000
        },
        module: {
            loaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ['latest', 'react', 'stage-0']
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

```
module: {
        loaders:[
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
```

and presets in the .babelrc

```
{
    'presets': ['latest', 'react', 'stage-0']
}
```

please refer to https://webpack.github.io/docs/usage.html

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue since I found a solution for myself. you can try it:

### --- here is the solution ---

If you've defined "presets" in ".babelrc" file
then you don't need to specify it in the "webpack.config.js" file, then delete it and it works well

---

and if you don't,
I recommend you to go to your ".babelrc" file and specify your presets there